# Dúvida referente a extensão do objeto Date

Tags: javascript, construtor

Estou tendo um problema cujo qual não consigo identificar a causa.

Tenho o seguinte construtor:

```
class ExtDate extends Date {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    foo() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

Teóricamente deveria fazer exatamente a mesma coisa que o construtor `Date`, só que com a função `foo()`.

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function ext(obj) {
    //Retorna uma string com o nome do construtor do parametro
    let constr = obj.constructor.toString().replace('()', '').split(' ')[1]; 

    construtores = {
        'Date' : ExtDate
    }

    return new construtores[constr](obj);
}
```

Até aqui tudo certo. Se eu inserir um objeto de data nesta função ele me retorna um objeto de data QUASE igual. A questão é: por que? Vejam:

```
var a = new Date('02-25-2019'); //Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var b = ext(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 12:46:41 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var c = new Date(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var d = new ExtDate(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 12:46:41 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

Resumindo, minha classe `ExtDate` está criando horários com o horário do navegador, enquanto o construtor original retorna com as horas 00 sempre. Mesmo quando insiro um valor de um objeto de data com 00 horas, ele me retorna o horário atual.

Por que isso ocorre, e como corrijo esse problema e semelhantes que possam vir a aparecer?

```js
class ExtDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

function ext(obj) {
  //Retorna uma string com o nome do construtor do parametro
  let constr = obj.constructor.toString().replace('()', '').split(' ')[1];

  construtores = {
    'Date': ExtDate
  }

  return new construtores[constr](obj);
}

var a = new Date('02-25-2019'); //Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var b = ext(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 12:46:41 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var c = new Date(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
var d = new ExtDate(a); //Mon Feb 25 2019 12:46:41 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o construtor de `ExtDate` sempre chama o construtor vazio de Date.

```js
class ExtDate extends Date {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

var extDate = new ExtDate('2019-01-01');
console.log(extDate);
```

```js
class ExtDate extends Date {
  constructor (param) {
    super(param)
  }
}

console.log(new ExtDate('2019-01-01'))
console.log(new ExtDate(new Date()))
```

Comment: Entendi.
No caso se eu estender um objeto que recebe vários parametros, posso fazer `constructor(...param) { super(...param) }` ou preciso especificar parametro por parametro?

Comment: Provavelmente a assinatura precisa ser idêntica.